# How to share a folder between my Mac and a Docker container

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, virtualization

Been spending some time trying to setup a Docker container with access to a folder on my Mac.

I know that you can use Docker Volumes to connect to a folder in the host, which on Mac ends up being Linux in VirtualBox, with the -v argument to docker run.

And given that, I figured that I could setup a shared folder in VirtualBox, which could then be mapped to the Docker container.

However, I've not been able to get the Shared Folder I've added to VB to show up.

Here's what I've done:

1) Added a Shared Folder in the VB admin

[image: VirtualBox Shared Folder config]

2) Restarted the VB OS with both docker-machine restart and via the VB app itself

3) Logged into the VB OS via docker-machine ssh

4) Did an ls -l of the root directory

The Users folder (which was there already in VB) shows up, but the folder I added (Projects) does not.

I can't figure out any reason why both folders would not appear. Anyone else having this problem?

Seems like with so many people talking about doing local Development with Docker, and so many devs using Macs, this would be a simple problem. But... alas...not for me so far.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can start `NFS` on your Mac with `sudo nfsd start` and share some directories, checking what is exported with `showmount -e` and then NFS mount from the VM via `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Hmm, never thought of native Mac sharing as an option. Tried that but getting an error when checking what is exported: "showmount: Cannot retrieve info from host: localhost: RPC failed:: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Bad file descriptor"

Comment: Move to docker 1.12 and forget about the man-in-the-middle, that is VeritualBox, which causes exactly these issues. On earlier versions, running via VirtualBox, you can only mount container directories into your OSX home directory

Comment: Have you considered using Docker for Mac? No VirtualBox required and the filesystem is a lot more natural as well. https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/mac

Comment: Docker4Mac, VirtualBox/Fusion shared folders are great for development but don't forget that any deployment in the cloud (production) won't have access to the mac folders. For those you will need to copy data directly to a volume using `docker cp` or to the host using `docker-machine scp`.

Comment: Wow, @ArunGupta, not sure how I got this far without knowing about Docker for Mac. That did the trick for me. Feel free to post as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Docker for Mac. No VirtualBox required and the filesystem access is a lot more natural as well.

More details at https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/mac.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it, and one of the easier ways is:

**Step 1:**
Make sure Docker.app has an entry for that folder/volume

[image]

**Step 2:**
Mount it with the `-v` flag and the path to that folder:

```
docker run --link cockroachdb -v /Users/gajensunthara/backups:/Users/gajensunthara/backups -it --rm --name backup-restore backup-restore
```